# Moving files into the htdocs folder in open Suse

Tags: linux, apache-httpd, opensuse

I'm new to Open Suse and have installed apache2, php8 and mysql and nginx. The problem is that when I try to move files to the htdocs folder I get the following message:

Could not make folder /srv/www/htdocs/assets.

I'll appreciate your input.

Comment: hm, why both apache2 and nginx? Both are HTTP servers with interfaces to PHP